# Redefining this in $.click event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you redefine `this` in a jQuery click event handler? I read a few years ago that Edge had an optional parameter that you could pass in to have this bound to something else, but does not seem to be the case any longer.

Comment: Binding `this` to something else and redefining `this` in an event handler are two different things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two common ways. I prefer using [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
$.fn.highlighter = function(){
    this.click($.proxy(function(){
        this.addClass('highlight');
    }, this));
};
```

The other common alternative is to assign `this` to `self` inside the function where you call the click handler.

```
$.fn.highlighter = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.click(function(){
        self.addClass('highlight');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the `this` value for a function.

```
var clickHandler = function () {
    // your click handler
};
```

And then:

```
$( stuff ).on( 'click', clickHandler.bind( context ) );
```

where `context` is the value you want to bind to `this` (within the handler).

*Note: You'll need to provide ES5-shim to older browsers.*